# Is L2 at a distance where the Earth totally eclipses the Sun?

Tags: orbit, lagrangian-points

What is the furthest from the Earth that still offers a total eclipse of the Sun? Is L2 inside that distance? (I assume so due the the halo orbit that is planned but perhaps there are numerous other reasons to fly around the L2 Lagrange point)

Comment: different but related (and has some great answers!): [Are there any (Lagrange) points in the Solar System in perpetual shade?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/3565/12102) See also [Is a sun-blocking orbit possible?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/28262/12102)

Comment: Another answer that may be helpful: [permanent lunar eclipse](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/203317/is-there-a-way-for-a-permanent-lunar-eclipse-or-another-object-to-always-be-in/203319#203319)

Answer (score 14):

No.

The [Earth's umbra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umbra,_penumbra_and_antumbra) extends 1.4 million km.
The [L2 point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_point#L2) is at 1.5 million km.
Even if perfectly aligned, the Earth [will only show as an annular eclipse](https://planetcalc.com/1897/), shading about 70% of the sun's disk.

However, the halo orbit of JWST will never pass through this region, nor even near it. The [operational requirements](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/56047/why-are-eclipses-of-the-james-webb-by-the-earth-or-moon-not-permitted-during-the) demand that the telescope never pass through any part of the Earth or Moon shadow.

Additionally, the rather large Halo orbit is chosen to maximize stability, specifically to minimize thruster fuel usage required to keep the probe in the orbit, as discussed here:
[https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/15167/are-large-halo-orbits-around-l₁s-and-l₂s-preferred-over-small-orbits-for-reaso](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/15167/are-large-halo-orbits-around-l%E2%82%81s-and-l%E2%82%82s-preferred-over-small-orbits-for-reaso).

JWST orbit illustrated, the **circle is *not* the Earth**, it is the Moon's orbit.
[image]

Comment: 10355/what-does-the-sun-earth-moon-system-look-like-from-the-sun-earth-l-2-point?rq=1
Has some more graphics and calculations.

Comment: > The operational requirements demand that the telescope never pass through any part of the Earth or Moon shadow.
why?  Is this to guarantee the JWST solar power arrays are drawing full solar power?

Comment: @Sheldon https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/56047/why-are-eclipses-of-the-james-webb-by-the-earth-or-moon-not-permitted-during-the